# unable to refactor Scala code to make it more readable

Tags: scala, playframework-2.6

I struggle to understand `Scala` and thus thought to refactor a piece of code to make it more de-sugared. But I am unable to do so.

The original code is

```
def index(signupMessage:String = "") = addToken { //addToken is of CSRFAddToken
        silhouette.UserAwareAction { implicit request =>
        println(s"index action called with request ${utilities.printPlayHttpRequest(request)}")
          //TODOM - fix as signup value is coming up as ;signup=error or ;signup=success instead of just success or error
        println(s"index page's argument "+signupMessage)
        val Token(name, value) = CSRF.getToken.get
        println(s"Token name ${name}, value ${value}")
        Ok(views.html.index(signupMessage,messagesApi("app.title")(langs.availables(0))))
      }
    }
```

I want to de-sugar the code and make calls more explicit. I am thinking of something in the following line

```
def index(signupMessage:String = "") = {
    val block:Action[AnyContent] = (implicit request) =>{ //THE ERROR IS HERE - '=>' expected but ')' found
      println(s"index action called with request ${utilities.printPlayHttpRequest(request)}")
      //TODOM - fix as signup value is coming up as ;signup=error or ;signup=success instead of just success or error
      println(s"index page's argument "+signupMessage)
      val Token(name, value) = CSRF.getToken.get
      println(s"Token name ${name}, value ${value}")
      Ok(views.html.index(signupMessage,messagesApi("app.title")(langs.availables(0))))
    }
    val silhouttedCode = silhouette.UserAwareAction.apply(block)
    addToken.apply(silhouettedCode)
  }
```

the above piece of code doesn't compile. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what's the compilation error?

Comment: I added it as comment - //THE ERROR IS HERE - '=>' expected but ')' found

Comment: What happens if you remove the parens around "implicit request"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to write your `Action` like this:

```
val block = Action { implicit request =>
  // Rest of code here
}
```

See [the docs for Actions](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaActions).